# PHP move_uploaded_file throw else

Tags: php

i wrote a code to upload an image like this

```
if (isset($_FILES['fotonya'])) {
                            # code...
                            $direktori = "assets/img/";
                            $tempatFoto = $direktori.$_FILES['fotonya']['name'];
                            $tipeGambar = strtolower(pathinfo($tempatFoto, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
                            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fotonya']['tmp_name'], $tempatFoto)) {
                                # code...
                                echo "zxczxc";
                            } else {
                                var_dump($_FILES);
                            }
                            //$sql = "INSERT INTO tes VALUES('', '".$tempatFoto."')";
                        } else {
                        }
```

but when i run these it throwing to var_dump

```
array(1) { ["fotonya"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(5) "2.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(33) "D:\Software\xampp\tmp\php5B77.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(281066) } }
```

how this can be fixed? tx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please check the directory permission, maybe there is no writable access. It seems your code is fine.
> You can check directory is writable or not by calling this function `is_writable($directory_path)`